# Fetching required data from table based on key

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I have a data set in a file, consisting of three columns (IP address, port, domainname) as shown below:

```
172.56.146.16 61981 r5---sn-uhvcpax0n5-x5ue.googlevideo.com
172.56.146.13 64576 r2---sn-uhvcpax0n5-x5ue.googlevideo.com
172.56.146.46 56483 ssl.gstatic.com
172.56.146.14 57054 r3---sn-uhvcpax0n5-x5ue.googlevideo.com
172.56.146.14 58157 r3---sn-uhvcpax0n5-x5ue.googlevideo.com
172.56.146.18 62666 ssl.gstatic.com
172.56.146.15 55682 r4---sn-uhvcpax0n5-x5ue.googlevideo.com
172.56.146.16 52234 r5---sn-uhvcpax0n5-x5ue.googlevideo.com
172.56.146.59 57106 ssl.gstatic.com
172.56.146.18 58897 ssl.gstatic.com
172.56.146.16 52258 r5---sn-uhvcpax0n5-x5ue.googlevideo.com
172.56.146.15 55694 r4---sn-uhvcpax0n5-x5ue.googlevideo.com
172.56.146.32 64281 ssl.gstatic.com
172.56.146.39 60581 ssl.gstatic.com
172.56.146.13 57137 r2---sn-uhvcpax0n5-x5ue.googlevideo.com
172.56.146.14 64763 r3---sn-uhvcpax0n5-x5ue.googlevideo.com
172.56.146.13 57135 r2---sn-uhvcpax0n5-x5ue.googlevideo.com
172.56.146.15 51318 r4---sn-uhvcpax0n5-x5ue.googlevideo.com
```

I also have a key set in a file, consisting of only IP address and port:

```
172.56.146.15 49333
172.56.146.16 52233
172.56.146.46 56483
172.56.146.14 58928
172.56.146.16 61981
172.56.146.13 64576
172.56.146.14 58157
172.56.146.18 62666
172.56.146.15 55682
172.56.146.14 57054
```

Now I want to consider all rows from the key set one by one, give that as input to my data set and in return I should be able to get the domain name from the data set for each key (IP address and port taken from key set).

For example, for `172.56.146.15 49333` I can have the result "domain not found", and for `172.56.146.46 56483`, I should get the result `ssl.gstatic.com` and so on. Can anyone let me know how can I do that using shell commands or scripting so that the resulting output is as follows (with one to one correspondence with keys from the key set) :

```
domain not found
ssl.gstatic.com
r5---sn-uhvcpax0n5-x5ue.googlevideo.com
```

Comment: you should provide some starter code, you can't expect us to do this for you...

Comment: And what would the output look like exactly? The domain appended to the key? Just the domain? Does the order of the lines in the output matter?

Comment: just answered above. the output should be in form of single column contains the domain-names as shown above.

Comment: @Seekheart : even if some help on the direction, that may be good. for e.g., i was just trying to see how can i generate a unique key (as a function of both ip/port-no) using python. i know there may be multiple ways, but any simple/quick solution will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two solutions, both reading the data file into an array, then looking up the array value for each line in the key file.

1. "Pure" Bash (only built-ins):

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   # Declare associative array
   declare -A datafile

   # Read data file into associative array
   while read -r ip_addr port domain; do
       datafile["$ip_addr $port"]="$domain"
   done < "$1"

   # Look up value for each key from key file in array
   while IFS= read -r key; do
       # Use parameter expansion to print "not found" if key is not in array
       printf "%s\n" "${datafile[$key]:-domain not found}"
   done < "$2"
   ```

   This is called as follows:

   ```
   ./SO.sh data keys
   ```

   where `SO.sh` is the name of the script file, `data` is the data file and `keys` the file with the keys.
2. Awk:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/awk -f

   # Process first file, read into array
   NR == FNR {
       datafile[$1, $2] = $3
       next
   }

   # Look up value for key
   {
       if (datafile[$1, $2] == "")
           print "domain not found"
       else
           print datafile[$1, $2]
   }
   ```

   This is called, assuming it is stored in `SO.awk`, as follows:

   ```
   ./SO.awk data keys
   ```

The awk solution will be faster by orders of magnitude for large files.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r ip foo bar; do
  grep "$ip $foo" dataset
  [[ $? != 0 ]] && echo "$ip $foo domain not found"
done < keys
```

Output:

```
172.56.146.15 49333 domain not found
172.56.146.16 52233 domain not found
172.56.146.46 56483 ssl.gstatic.com
172.56.146.14 58928 domain not found
172.56.146.16 61981 r5---sn-uhvcpax0n5-x5ue.googlevideo.com
172.56.146.13 64576 r2---sn-uhvcpax0n5-x5ue.googlevideo.com
172.56.146.14 58157 r3---sn-uhvcpax0n5-x5ue.googlevideo.com
172.56.146.18 62666 ssl.gstatic.com
172.56.146.15 55682 r4---sn-uhvcpax0n5-x5ue.googlevideo.com
172.56.146.14 57054 r3---sn-uhvcpax0n5-x5ue.googlevideo.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
#!/bin/sh

while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    if grep -q -s "$line" table.txt; then
        result=($(grep -s $line table.txt))
        echo ${result[2]}
    else
        echo "domain not found"
    fi
done < "$1"
```

The run:

```
./myscript.sh key.txt
```

Results:

```
domain not found
domain not found
ssl.gstatic.com
domain not found
r5---sn-uhvcpax0n5-x5ue.googlevideo.com
r2---sn-uhvcpax0n5-x5ue.googlevideo.com
r3---sn-uhvcpax0n5-x5ue.googlevideo.com
ssl.gstatic.com
r4---sn-uhvcpax0n5-x5ue.googlevideo.com
r3---sn-uhvcpax0n5-x5ue.googlevideo.com
```